# Time specific threading

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, dictionary

I'm writing a program that has a dictionary with timings in (as well as other information) but the key is I need to create a individual thread for each entry that when the thread is running, do a simple one line command then sleep for an alloted time(which is passed from the dictionary) and then re-run. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import time


class worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,timer):
        while True:
            print("job %s" % timer)
            time.sleep(timer/100)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    mydict = {1:150, 2:250, 3:350}

    for values in mydict.keys():
        new_worker_thread = worker(values)
```

Each value in the dictionary represents a time (in milliseconds) and this needs to be passed to the thread and then run until stopped.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Jim

## EDIT

Sorry this may not have been clear.

The for loop I am using only seems to create a thread for the first value in the dictionary. I am having a problem getting all the threads to run with the correct timings

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: @RémiBecheras Sorry just edited in the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the expected output(I think, correct me if I'm wrong):

```
class worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, timer):
        self.timer = timer
        super(worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("job %s" % self.timer)
            time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    mydict = {1:150, 2:250, 3:350}

    for values in mydict.keys():
        print(values)
        new_worker_thread = worker(values)
        new_worker_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to start the thread after creating it:

```
new_worker_thread = worker(values).start()
```